# gtk python grid resize

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, gtk3

Following the official tutorials about containers.
I have the follwoing code

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="test")

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(grid)

        button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 1")
        button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 2")
        button3 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 3")
        button4 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 4")
        button5 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 5")
        button6 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 6")

        grid.add(button1)
        grid.attach(button2, 1, 0, 2, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(button3, button1, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 2)
        grid.attach_next_to(button4, button3, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 2, 1)
        grid.attach(button5, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(button6, button5, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)


win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

All good when I run it

[image]

However if I resize it the grid won't resize with the main window.

Any pointers how to make the grid resize?
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the buttons to expand. Example:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="test")

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(grid)

        button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 1", expand = True)
        button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 2", expand = True)
        button3 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 3", expand = True)
        button4 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 4", expand = True)
        button5 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 5", expand = True)
        button6 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 6", expand = True)

        grid.add(button1)
        grid.attach(button2, 1, 0, 2, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(button3, button1, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 2)
        grid.attach_next_to(button4, button3, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 2, 1)
        grid.attach(button5, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(button6, button5, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)


win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. "expand = True" does the job. May be I should read documentation more :D

Comment: Is there a way to expand only in one direction?

Comment: @lefrcom Use [vexpand](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--vexpand)

Comment: Or [hexpand](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--hexpand)